# Android intersection of views not working

Tags: android, intersection, android-framelayout, rect

I have two very simple views set up in Android:

[image: screenshot]

and here is my code to see if they overlap but for some reason the code always returns "IS NOT overlapping":

private FrameLayout firstView;
    private FrameLayout secondView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firstView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.numberOne);
    secondView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.numberTwo);

    if (containsView(secondView, firstView)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IS overlapping", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "IS NOT overlapping", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public boolean containsView(View firstView, View secondView){
    int[] pointA = new int[2];
    firstView.getLocationOnScreen(pointA);
    Rect rectA = new Rect(pointA[0], pointA[1], pointA[0] + firstView.getWidth(), pointA[1] + firstView.getHeight());

    int[] pointB = new int[2];
    secondView.getLocationOnScreen(pointB);
    Rect rectB = new Rect(pointB[0], pointB[1], pointB[0] + secondView.getWidth(), pointB[1] + secondView.getHeight());

    return Rect.intersects(rectA, rectB);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Checking the Views locations before they got measured and being drawn to the screen. the call `firstView.getWidth` is probably 0. you can check it by logging.

add `TreeObserver` or something like: `secondView.addOnLayoutChangeListener`.

by the way i didn't check if your intersect algorithm is correct, only notified you about your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for Activity to layout itself. 
You could use a handler for that:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        containsView(secondView, firstView)     
    }
});
```

If you put the call to containsView into a clicklistener (of a button or anything else), you don't have that problem, as the layouting will be finished by then.